# How to create persistent data using Room Database

Tags: android, android-room

I want to know how app does not lose data even if app clear data from app storage. In case whenever  I cleared  app data from app storage I lost everything data. I want to make private data when I clear app storage of my app data will not be  lost. I'm  using room persistence library.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<MainCategory> catList = new ArrayList<>();
    ImageView backPressedBtn;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;
    Context mContext;
    CategoryViewModel catViewModel;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_category);
        //Calling ViewModel
        initViewModel();
        //Hooks
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        //Recyclerview
        initRecyclerview();
        //Sample Data Provider
        //catList = SampleDataProvider.getSampleData();
        //catList = catViewModel.mCatList;
        //Show Data
        showDataInRecyclerView();
    }

    //Calling View Model Method
    private void initViewModel() {
        Observer<List<MainCategory>> mainCategoryObserver = new Observer<List<MainCategory>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<MainCategory> mainCategoryList) {
                catList.clear();
                catList.addAll(mainCategoryList);
                if (categoryAdapter == null) {

                    categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(MainCategoryActivity.this, catList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
                } else {
                    categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };

        catViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CategoryViewModel.class);
        catViewModel.mCatList.observe(MainCategoryActivity.this, mainCategoryObserver);
    }

    //Menu Button Creating
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //Menu Items Actions
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.menu_add_category:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Add New Category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                addSampleData();
                //Open Add New Catgory
                //openAddCategoryActivity();
                return true;
            case R.id.about_us:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked About Us", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.rate_us:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Rate Us", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void addSampleData() {

        catViewModel.addSampleData();
    }

    private void showDataInRecyclerView() {
        /*categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(mContext, catList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);*/
    }

    private void initRecyclerview() {
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    //Open New Activity to add Some New Category
    public void openAddCategoryActivity() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Open Add Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddCategory.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

CategoryAdapter.java

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder> {
    Context cContext;
    List<MainCategory> mainCategoryList;
    
    public CategoryAdapter(Context cContext, List<MainCategory> mainCategoryList) {
        this.cContext = cContext;
        this.mainCategoryList = mainCategoryList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.catgory_row_item, parent, false);
        CategoryViewHolder viewHolder = new CategoryViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.categoryTitle.setText(mainCategoryList.get(position).getCategoryName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mainCategoryList == null ? 0 : mainCategoryList.size();
    }

    public static class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cardView;
        TextView categoryTitle;
        public CategoryViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_cardview);
            categoryTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_category_title);
        }
    }
}
```

AppDatabase.java

```
//Singleton Class
@Database(entities = {MainCategory.class},version = 2)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="storyhub.db";
    public static volatile AppDatabase instance;
    public static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    public abstract CategoryDao categoryDao();

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context dbContext){
        if (instance == null){
            synchronized (LOCK){
                if (instance == null){
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(dbContext.getApplicationContext()
                            ,AppDatabase.class,DATABASE_NAME)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

MainCategory.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "category")
public class MainCategory {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryid")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int categoryId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryname")
    private String categoryName;

    @Ignore
    public void MainCategory() {

    }

    @Ignore
    public MainCategory(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public MainCategory(int categoryId, String categoryName) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }
    
    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MainCategory{" +
                "categoryId=" + categoryId +
                ", categoryName='" + categoryName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

CategoryDao.java

```
@Dao
public interface CategoryDao {

    //Insert and Update
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertCategory(MainCategory mainCategory);

    //Insert All
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertAllCategory(List<MainCategory> mainCategoryList);

    //Delete
    @Delete
    void deleteCategory(MainCategory mainCategory);

    //Retrieve  Data All Data
    @Query("SELECT * FROM category")
    LiveData<List<MainCategory>> getAllCategory();

    //Retrieve  Data By Id
    @Query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE categoryid= :categoryId")
    MainCategory getCategoryById(int categoryId);

   // Delete  All Data
    @Query("DELETE FROM category")
    int deleteAllCategory();

    //Count Data
    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM category")
    int getCount();
}
```

CategoryViewModel.java

```
public class CategoryViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public LiveData<List<MainCategory>> mCatList;
    private CategoryRepository mCategoryRepository;

    public CategoryViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mCategoryRepository = CategoryRepository.getInstance(application.getApplicationContext());
        mCatList = mCategoryRepository.mCatList;
    }

    public void addSampleData() {

        mCategoryRepository.addSampleData();
    }
}
```

CategoryRepository.java

```
public class CategoryRepository {

    private static CategoryRepository ourInstance;
    private AppDatabase mAppDatabase;
    //ViewModel Data
    public LiveData<List<MainCategory>> mCatList;
private  Executor mExecutor =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public static CategoryRepository getInstance(Context context){
        return ourInstance = new CategoryRepository(context);
    }
    private CategoryRepository(Context context){

        //mCatList = SampleDataProvider.getSampleData();
        mAppDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(context);

        mCatList = getAllCategorydata();
    }

    public void addSampleData() {
        mExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               // mAppDatabase.categoryDao().insertAllCategory(mCatList);
                mAppDatabase.categoryDao().insertAllCategory(SampleDataProvider.getSampleData());
            }
        });
    }

    private LiveData<List<MainCategory>> getAllCategorydata(){
        return  mAppDatabase.categoryDao().getAllCategory();

    }
}
```

SampleDataProvider.java

```
public class SampleDataProvider {
    public static final String SAMPLE_TEXT_1 = "A";
    public static final String SAMPLE_TEXT_2 = "AA";
    public static final String SAMPLE_TEXT_3 = "AAA";
    public static final String SAMPLE_TEXT_4 = "AAAA";

    public static List<MainCategory> getSampleData(){

        List<MainCategory> mCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        mCategoryList.add(new MainCategory(SAMPLE_TEXT_1));
        mCategoryList.add(new MainCategory(SAMPLE_TEXT_2));
        mCategoryList.add(new MainCategory(SAMPLE_TEXT_3));
        mCategoryList.add(new MainCategory(SAMPLE_TEXT_4));
        return mCategoryList;
    }
}
```

build.gradle(:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codewithcup.roomdataapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
}
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
//Room Database Version
ext {
    roomVersion = '2.2.0'
}
```

Comment: please elaborate your query.

Comment: I want to know how app does not lose data even if app clear data from app storage. In case whenever  I cleared  app data from app storage I lost everything data. I want to make private data when I clear app storage of my app data will not be  lost. I'm  using room persistence library

Comment: Can you share your Room database classes ?

Comment: @Crisic sure... already posted